# How to clear navigation header view?

Tags: java, android, xml, view, navigation-drawer

I designed an app with two layouts(nav_header_main.xml & nav_header_main_user.xml) if the user logged in means nav_header_main_user.xml should be shown, if user logged out nav_header_main should shown. I got the view but its not clearing each time. In menu we'll clear like`navigationView.getMenu().clear();`.  I need to know how to clear for navigation header view.

The first xml file(nav_header_main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/headerView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_screen_logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_round_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the second xml file(nav_header_main_user.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/user_headerView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player_name_after_signin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/player_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_after_user_signin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
        android:text="@string/email_email_com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my java code will be like,

```
if( sharedpreference.getString("PlayerID",null)!=null )
   {  
        navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main_user);
   }
 else
   {
        navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
   }
```

Now i'm missing the code, to clear the xml files according to that. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please add code how and where you are clearing and also show both xml files

Comment: added both xml code and java code. can you please help me with this?